Парсил сайт, еще вчера все работало, а сегодня вылетает ошибка, ничего не менял!В чем может быть проблема?
    headers = {
        "Accept" : "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.6367.61 Safari/537.36"
    }
    
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
    options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
    #options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    options.add_argument("start-maximized") # // https://stackoverflow.com/a/26283818/1689770
    options.add_argument("enable-automation")#  // https://stackoverflow.com/a/43840128/1689770
    #options.add_argument("--headless")#  // only if you are ACTUALLY running headless
    #options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")# //https://stackoverflow.com/a/50725918/1689770
    options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")# //https://stackoverflow.com/a/50725918/1689770
    options.add_argument("--disable-browser-side-navigation")# //https://stackoverflow.com/a/49123152/1689770
    options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")# //https://stackoverflow.com/a/43840128/1689770
    options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
    
    #options.add_argument("--proxy-server=31.204.2.182:9142")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)

При запуске вылезает такая ошибка:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Dev\bamper_parsing_top_mark\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 198, in _new_conn
    sock = connection.create_connection(
  File "C:\Dev\bamper_parsing_top_mark\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 85, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Dev\bamper_parsing_top_mark\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] 

Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Узнал информацию, у меня установлена версия Хрома 124.0.6367.61 и к данной версии на данный момент нет совместимого драйвера( нашел в обсуждениях на оф сайте). Там же предложена идея откатить на 123 версию
